# How to output city by IP address to stdout?

Tags: linux, ip, city

I have a list of IP addresses in the ip.txt file (there are a lot of them).
I used `ipinfo.io`  services to search data by IP and `sed` to cut out only the city.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    curl ipinfo.io/$ip >> test.txt
    sed -i '/city/!d' test.txt
    cat /dev/null > test.txt
done < ip.txt
```

However, the script doesn`t display the city in a loop over all IPs (only works on individual data), but displays a lot of unnecessary information.
For example, for the following IPs (generated automatically):

```
97.108.178.66
98.10.198.56
201.12.36.90
```

My output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   332  100   332    0     0   2145      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2155
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   323  100   323    0     0   1345      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1340
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   266  100   266    0     0   1426      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1430
```

Required output:

```
  "city": "Toronto",
  "city": "Rochester",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If you want the cities, why do you overwrite the result?

Comment: @tink I couldn't do it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you're trying to capture the cities in a text file or display them.  If you want them stored, don't overwrite the results.

```
$ cat tmp 
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    curl ipinfo.io/$ip >> test.txt 2>/dev/null
    sed -i '/city/!d' test.txt
done < ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt 
97.108.178.66
98.10.198.56
201.12.36.90
$ ./tmp 
$ cat test.txt 
  "city": "Toronto",
  "city": "Rochester",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
$
```

If you just want to see them on screen:

```
$ cat tmp 
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    curl ipinfo.io/$ip 2>&1 | sed  '/city/!d'
done < ip.txt
$ ./tmp 
  "city": "Toronto",
  "city": "Rochester",
  "city": "Rio de Janeiro",
$
```

Comment: Yes, the second option is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand the differences between your own approach and what I did there, or do you need an explanation? @Lib

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the extra file